# gradient fill and canvas size?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

the code below displays a radial gradient filled rectangle. If I un-comment the two lines that set canvas' width and height, it displays a black rectangle instead of a gradient filled one. why? how to set the width and height and still be able to show a gradient?

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function on_load(e) {
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var canvas = container.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(30, 30, 10, 30, 30, 30);

        gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0,1)");
        gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");

        context.fillStyle = gradient;

        //canvas.width = 150;
        //canvas.height = 150;

        context.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 60);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="on_load()"><div id="container"></div></body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change canvas size before using its context

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that setting width or height clears the canvas and its settings.